# How to copy portion of char buffer into char[]?

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm trying to read the process name from `/proc/[pid]/stat` and that is mostly successful. Yet valgrind complains about something, and the process crashes after some time. My code comes from procps-ng with a few modifications. What I've attempted to do is read the file into a buffer, then find a pointer to the start and end of the process name in that buffer. After that `strncpy` copies the selected section into the destination buffer and then I add null to the end.

Is this the wrong approach?

The relevant bit of code is here:

```
rc = file2str(path,"stat",  &ub);
if (rc <= 0) return rc;

ub.buf = strchr(ub.buf, '(');
if (!ub.buf) return 0;
ub.buf++;
tmp = strrchr(ub.buf, ')');
if (!tmp || !tmp[1]) return 0;

strncpy(name, ub.buf, (tmp - ub.buf));
name[tmp - ub.buf + 1] = 0;
return (tmp - ub.buf);
```

The same `file2str` function is called from another place where it works reliably. I've tried to invoke it in the same way, so I am at a loss for why it fails here.

Valgrind says:

```
Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s) 
    at 0x4C4A912: read (read.c:26)                                   
    by 0x10D2F9: read (unistd.h:47)                                  
    by 0x10D2F9: file2str (procs.c:98)                               
    by 0x10D6B0: stat2name (procs.c:159)                             
    by 0x10DEAA: walk_and_draw (pidgrid.c:313)                       
    by 0x4C55D72: trecurse_r (tsearch.c:739)                         
    by 0x4C55D62: trecurse_r (tsearch.c:736)                         
    by 0x4C55D62: trecurse_r (tsearch.c:736)                         
    by 0x4C55D62: trecurse_r (tsearch.c:736)                         
    by 0x4C55D62: trecurse_r (tsearch.c:736)                         
    by 0x4C55D72: trecurse_r (tsearch.c:739)                         
    by 0x4C55D72: trecurse_r (tsearch.c:739)                         
    by 0x4C56B92: trecurse_r (tsearch.c:736)   
    by 0x4C56B92: twalk_r (tsearch.c:753)
```

Full code listing can be found here: https://github.com/robbieh/xscreensaver-pidgrid

**edit #1**

The var `name` gets filled. In this case with "Isolated Web Co". That gets written into `text` which contains "PID: 1737571 UID: 1000 RSS: 83241 VSIZE: 3037233152 STATE: S OOMSCORE: 670 -- Isolated Web Co".

Here's what I get out of GDB:

```
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=140737346060608) at pthread_kill.c:44
#1  __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=140737346060608) at pthread_kill.c:80
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=140737346060608, signo=signo@entry=6) at pthread_kill.c:91
#3  0x00007ffff7b03476 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
#4  0x00007ffff7ae97b7 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#5  0x00007ffff7b4a5e6 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7c9c13d "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:155
#6  0x00007ffff7b61adc in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff7c99e4b "realloc(): invalid old size") at malloc.c:5543
#7  0x00007ffff7b65534 in _int_realloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7cd5c60 <main_arena>, oldp=oldp@entry=0x555555cd1680, oldsize=<optimized out>, nb=nb@entry=1040) at malloc.c:4718
#8  0x00007ffff7b66149 in __GI___libc_realloc (oldmem=0x555555cd1690, bytes=1024) at malloc.c:3372
#9  0x00007ffff79c565f in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
#10 0x00007ffff79c56be in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
#11 0x00007ffff79c585c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
#12 0x00007ffff79d370e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
#13 0x00007ffff79da544 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
#14 0x00007ffff79dff6f in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
#15 0x00007ffff79c4c88 in FT_Load_Glyph () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
#16 0x00007ffff7a1371b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
#17 0x00007ffff79c5161 in FT_Load_Glyph () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
#18 0x00007ffff7f941aa in XftFontLoadGlyphs () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXft.so.2
#19 0x00007ffff7f990f3 in XftGlyphRender () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXft.so.2
#20 0x00007ffff7f99333 in XftDrawGlyphs () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXft.so.2
#21 0x00007ffff7f9994b in XftDrawStringUtf8 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXft.so.2
#22 0x0000555555559f97 in walk_and_draw (what=<optimized out>, which=<optimized out>, closure=0x555555592040) at pidgrid.c:326
#23 0x00007ffff7bdfd73 in trecurse_r (vroot=0x555555bbb790, action=0x5555555597b0 <walk_and_draw>, closure=0x555555592040) at tsearch.c:739
#24 0x00007ffff7bdfd73 in trecurse_r (vroot=0x555555bb5fb0, action=0x5555555597b0 <walk_and_draw>, closure=0x555555592040) at tsearch.c:739
#25 0x00007ffff7bdfd73 in trecurse_r (vroot=0x555555baaff0, action=0x5555555597b0 <walk_and_draw>, closure=0x555555592040) at tsearch.c:739
#26 0x00007ffff7bdfd63 in trecurse_r (vroot=0x555555bc0f70, action=0x5555555597b0 <walk_and_draw>, closure=0x555555592040) at tsearch.c:736
#27 0x00007ffff7bdfd63 in trecurse_r (vroot=0x555555bece70, action=0x5555555597b0 <walk_and_draw>, closure=0x555555592040) at tsearch.c:736
#28 0x00007ffff7bdfd73 in trecurse_r (vroot=0x555555b95070, action=0x5555555597b0 <walk_and_draw>, closure=0x555555592040) at tsearch.c:739
#29 0x00007ffff7bdfd73 in trecurse_r (vroot=0x555555ae5470, action=0x5555555597b0 <walk_and_draw>, closure=0x555555592040) at tsearch.c:739
#30 0x00007ffff7bdfd73 in trecurse_r (vroot=0x555555a35870, action=0x5555555597b0 <walk_and_draw>, closure=0x555555592040) at tsearch.c:739
#31 0x00007ffff7be0b83 in trecurse_r (closure=0x555555592040, action=0x5555555597b0 <walk_and_draw>, vroot=0x5555555a9b60) at tsearch.c:739
#32 __GI___twalk_r (vroot=0x5555555a9b60, action=0x5555555597b0 <walk_and_draw>, closure=0x555555592040) at tsearch.c:753
#33 0x000055555555a35b in pidgrid_draw (dpy=<optimized out>, window=<optimized out>, closure=0x555555592040) at pidgrid.c:616
#34 0x00005555555586ef in run_screenhack_table (ft=<optimized out>, window2=<optimized out>, window=<optimized out>, dpy=<optimized out>) at screenhack.c:593
#35 main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at screenhack.c:996
```

Comment: How do you initialize `ub.buf` before calling `file2strZ()`? `file2str()` will allocate memory if it's `NULL`. But the error suggests that it's an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @Barmar - in file2str there is a test for null and a calloc, I wondered the same thing. Maybe not every caller zeroes it though

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the function `file2str`. The mere fact that this function appears to work properly in one situation does not necessarily mean that it will work reliably in all situations.

Comment: Step through the program in the debugger.

Comment: @Barmar ub is allocated on the stack:  static __thread struct utlbuf_s ub = { NULL, 0 }; That's the same way it is being initialized in simple_readproc, the place where it works reliably.

Comment: Yeah, I found that on github. I'm not sure why it's not working. That's what the debugger is for.

Comment: or if denug not possible for some reasong  printf the  ub buffer address and various sizes each time round that while loop, I am sure it will be clear whats happening

Comment: Back to the original question: am I copying the chars around correctly? Valgrind continues to complain about it. In particular in `file2str` where the null byte is assigned I get an occasional "Invalid write of size 1".